# Checkbox on Datagrid for ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, checkbox

I have a data grid on my project with a Checkbox as a TemplateField; but I can't acces the `checkbox.checked` property. Does anyone have any idea?

My ASP code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVP" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DSP">
     <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-Width="5%" FooterStyle-Width ="5%">
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectCb" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
               </ItemTemplate>
               <FooterStyle Width="5%"/>
               <HeaderStyle Width="5%"/>
               <ItemStyle Width="5%"/>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Answers" HeaderText="Options" SortExpression="Answers" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My VB code behind:

```
     Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles buttonNext.Click
    Dim SelectedBox As Boolean = False
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GVP.Rows
        Dim cb As CheckBox = row.FindControl("SelectCb")
        If cb IsNot Nothing AndAlso cb.Checked Then
            SelectedBox = True
            Dim RID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GVP.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value)
        Else
            ShowMessage("You did not select anything")
        End if
```

Comment: Try 'SelectedBox = ctype(row.FindControl("SelectCb"),TextBox).checked'. This should work.

Comment: what do you mean by "can't acces the checkbox.checked property"? is it throwing an error? if so, what is the error?

Comment: When the debugger gets to the `If cb.Checked Then` part; it always returns 'False' even when cb is declared with CType or DirectCast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem really resided on the `Page_Load` where I was binding the grid to the datasource; I deleted it and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In gvTest.Rows
    Dim cb As CheckBox = row.FindControl("SelectCb")
    If (CType(row.FindControl("SelectCb"), CheckBox)).Checked = True Then
       SelectedBox = True
       Dim RID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(gvTest.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value)
    End If    
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do here and how you are testing but my guess is that this is because you are not checking for row type.  So the first row is actually the header and therefore will not have a checkbox at all (and you will get the message).

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GVP.Rows
    If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim cb As CheckBox ...
```